# comparing the results from 2 functions and hiding results if they are the same

Tags: php, mysql

I'm using 2 functions. The first function pulls the following information:

```
$availcourse = "SELECT * FROM organization_courses oc left join course c on oc.courseid=c.id WHERE organizationid=$orgid ORDER By category";
$aresults = mysql_query($availcourse);
```

The second function pulls this information:

```
$depcourse = "SELECT * FROM organization_dep_courses odc left join course c on odc.courseid=c.id WHERE depid=$departmentid ORDER By category";
$dcresults = mysql_query($depcourse);
```

My question is, how would I keep records from function #1 from displaying in function #2 if they are the same? Obvious similarities in both results will be the courseid

I hope that makes sense.

Comment: I guess they will never be the same, if one reads from `organization_courses, course` and the other reads from `organization_dep_courses, course`. Perhaps some clarification here would make your answer more plausible. What are those tables structures and what kind of comparation are you trying to do?

Comment: You can join them and get the distinct(*).

Comment: its actually for a form that i did. the form in column 1 displays the results from function 1, the available courses. column 2 displays the results from function 2, the already assigned courses. the courseid from the results in both will be the same. what i am trying to do is if the courseid is already displayed in column 2(the assigned courses), i want to omit that data from displaying in column 1 (the available coruses).

Comment: So basically you want to remove courses you are currently assigned from the available courses list.

Comment: Any particular reason to be using `LEFT JOIN` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `organization_courses` and `organization_dep_courses` have the same number of columns and the columns are in the same order, you can use MySQL's [`UNION`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/union.html).

```
$query = '
  SELECT *
  FROM (
    (SELECT *
     FROM organization_courses oc
     LEFT JOIN course c ON oc.courseid = c.id
     WHERE organizationid = $orgid)
    UNION
    (SELECT *
     FROM organization_dep_courses odc
     LEFT JOIN course c ON odc.courseid = c.id
     WHERE depid = $departmentid)
  ) q
  GROUP BY q.courseid
  ORDER BY q.category
';
```

**Note**: Your SQL code is vulnerable to [SQL Injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection).

Comment: Just a note for future reference: the reason this would work is because `UNION` filters out duplicates. If you ever wanted to do a `UNION` query without this filtering happening, you'd want `UNION ALL`.

Comment: thanks a bunch, i'll have a go at it and btw, thanks for the note on SQL injection Aiias. I'll make sure to make the proper corrections!

Comment: Also note, UNIONS are slow.

Comment: ok, so i was able to get it working somewhat with Aiias's union suggestion by making a few minor adjustments, but there is one bug i am running into, i have an add and remove form attached to this now. when I add courses into the second column, it duplicates the results in the first column which is the union. How do I prevent the duplicates?

Comment: @Ansipants - See my edit. I have added a `GROUP BY` clause so that only unique `courseid`s are shown.

Comment: This prevents duplicates in the first column so thank you for that, however, this still shows the course in the first column after it is added to the second column which logically is because of the query. Do you think it would be better if i created an additional table which has a copy of the data from the union query and then do something like a subquery function that when a course is added from into column 2 it deletes the row from copied table? I hope that somewhat makes sense.

Comment: @Ansipants - I'm not sure what you mean. Are you referring to the columns of the tables not being in the same order?